# Stuck solving an ODE(IVP) with separation of variables

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve an IVP which has a particularity of having several variables which should be found with a set of conditions, which is:

$y'(t)=k y(t)(P-y(t))$

$y(0)=500$

$y(1)=1000$

$lim_{t->\infty}y(t)=50000$

By using the separation of variables method, I found that, after doing the integrations:

$\frac{\ln(y)-\ln(y-P)}{Pk}=t+C$

Which is where I get stuck. By trying to simplify I got:

$\frac{1}{kP}(\ln\frac{y}{y-P})=t+C$

$(e^\frac{1}{kp})(\frac{y}{y-P})=Ce^t$

$\frac{y}{y-P}=Ce^{(t-\frac{1}{kP})}$

Where, at the end:

$y(t)=\frac{-pCe^{(t-\frac{1}{kP})}}{1-e^{(t-\frac{1}{kP})}}$

Which does not meet the criteria for the IVP, so it should mean that I have messed up along the way, and I guess it's when I started using the logarithmic and exponential simplifications...

Any suggestions/corrections are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1k\int \frac1{y(P-y)}\, dy = t+c$$

$$\frac1k\int \frac1{Py}+\frac1{P(P-y)}\, dy = t+c$$

$$\frac1{Pk}\int \frac1{y}+\frac1{(P-y)}\, dy = t+c$$

$$\frac1{kP }\left( \ln y-\ln (P-y)\right)=t+c$$

$$\frac{y}{P-y}= A\exp\left(kPt \right)$$

I think you made a mistake when you take exponential. Note that $e^{AB} \ne e^A e^B$.

Edit:

$$y  = \frac{AP\exp(kPT)}{1+A\exp(kPt)}=\frac{P}{1+\frac{\exp(-kPt)}{A}}$$

We are told that as $t \to \infty$, the value converges. In that case, we need $kP>0$ and the exponential term vanishes. Hence $P=50000$.

Use information about $t=0$ to solve for $A$.

Finally use information about $t=1$ to solve for $k$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what properties or steps did you take from the previous to the last step? Also, I have tried imposing the IVP conditions, though the linear system is not getting solved.

Comment: I multiply $kP$ on both sides, then I take exponential on both sides. Let me include more guide to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you  so much :) now I got it, I don't know how I had missed out that. I also solved the linear system now by hand (hurrah for my reliance on solving them with Maxima!)